# How do I find javac.exe programmatically?

Tags: .net, environment-variables, java, javac

I'm calling javac from C# code. Originally I found its location only as follows:

```
protected static string JavaHome
{
    get
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
    }
}
```

However, I just installed the JDK on a new computer and found that it didn't automatically set the JAVA_HOME environment variable. *Requiring* an environment variable is unacceptable in any Windows application for the last decade, so I need a way to find javac if the JAVA_HOME environment variable is not set:

```
protected static string JavaHome
{
    get
    {
        string home = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(home) || !Directory.Exists(home))
        {
            // TODO: find the JDK home directory some other way.
        }

        return home;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it unacceptable?  How is the computer supposed to magically know where the executable is installed?  They are not mind readers, they are computers, you have to tell them what to do...

Comment: Because they don't properly synchronize across the environment, they're a pain to configure, and I'm sick of having to write convoluted instructions to users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are on Windows, use registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit

If you are not, you are pretty much stuck with env variables. You might find [this](http://www.chriskopec.com/blog/2009/jun/15/automatic-discovery-java_home-batch-file/) blog entry useful.

**Edited by 280Z28:**

Underneath that registry key is a CurrentVersion value. That value is used to find the Java home at the following location:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\{CurrentVersion}\JavaHome`

```
private static string javaHome;

protected static string JavaHome
{
    get
    {
        string home = javaHome;
        if (home == null)
        {
            home = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(home) || !Directory.Exists(home))
            {
                home = CheckForJavaHome(Registry.CurrentUser);
                if (home == null)
                    home = CheckForJavaHome(Registry.LocalMachine);
            }

            if (home != null && !Directory.Exists(home))
                home = null;

            javaHome = home;
        }

        return home;
    }
}

protected static string CheckForJavaHome(RegistryKey key)
{
    using (RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit"))
    {
        if (subkey == null)
            return null;

        object value = subkey.GetValue("CurrentVersion", null, RegistryValueOptions.None);
        if (value != null)
        {
            using (RegistryKey currentHomeKey = subkey.OpenSubKey(value.ToString()))
            {
                if (currentHomeKey == null)
                    return null;

                value = currentHomeKey.GetValue("JavaHome", null, RegistryValueOptions.None);
                if (value != null)
                    return value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: For the Linux users, I've come across this code sample, that does the same thing: http://agiletrack.net/samples/sample-detect-java.html

Comment: agiletrack.net url not working, please post how to detect java_home in linuc

Answer (score 1):

You should probably search the registry for a JDK installation address.

As an alternative, see [this](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5355033) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

For 64-bit OS (Windows 7), the registry key may be under

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit`

if you're running a 32-bit JDK. So if you've all written code based on the above, go test again.

I haven't yet got my head completely around the [Microsoft registry redirection/reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) stuff yet.